# sccm how to install specific KB update

Tags: c#, powershell, sccm

Is there any specific way to trigger an installation for a specific update available progmatically using SCCM.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about SCCM but you can look into https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc which has a bunch of Windows Update stuff including checking and installing specific KB numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the specific update from the [Windows Update Catalog](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Home.aspx) and create a program within SCCM with the following command: `wusa.exe <UpdateFileName>.msu /quiet /norestart`